# How to set different parameter ranges within a real valued chromosome using Pyevolve?

Tags: python, pyevolve

I'm trying to use pyevolve to implement a real valued genetic algorithm. (Example documentation is given here: http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/examples.html#example-2-real-numbers-gaussian-mutator)

The range of the parameters (20 in this example) can be set using `setParams` as follows:

`# Genome instance
genome = G1DList.G1DList(20)
genome.setParams(rangemin=-6.0, rangemax=6.0)`

However, the same range is applied to all 20.  I'd like to have different ranges for the parameters.  The way I tried to do it is changing the Initializators file.

The original relevant section within the file is:

```
    def G1DListInitializatorReal(genome, **args):
       """ Real initialization function of G1DList

        This initializator accepts the *rangemin* and *rangemax* genome parameters.

       """
       genome.clearList()

       for i in xrange(genome.listSize):
          randomReal = rand_uniform(genome.getParam("rangein", 0),
                            genome.getParam("rangemax", 100))
          genome.append(randomReal)
```

My modification (assuming that the first 15 have one range and the last 5 have another range) is this:

```
     def G1DListInitializatorReal(genome, **args):

       genome.clearList()

       for i in xrange(0,15):
          print i
          randomReal = rand_uniform(genome.getParam("rangein_1", 0),
                            genome.getParam("rangemax_1", 100))
          genome.append(randomReal)
       for j in xrange(15,20):
          print j
          randomReal2 = rand_uniform(genome.getParam("rangein_2", 0),
                            genome.getParam("rangemax_2", 100))
          genome.append(randomReal2)
```

I added the printing of indices i and j to make sure that I know this one is being called. I've put the modified `Initializators` file in the same folder as my code but when I run it, it calls the original one from elsewhere.  I feel like I'm missing more changes that I need to make in pyevolve, or I'm not calling `Initializators` correctly, or...I don't know.

How can I successfully change the range of my chromosome parameters in pyevolve?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one out there knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the alleles, see this [example](http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/examples.html#example-11-the-use-of-alleles).

Create the allele:

```
alleles = GAllele.GAlleles()
```

Create the range for each parameter:

```
alleles.add(GAllele.GAlleleRange(range_min, range_max))
```

Set the parameters:

```
genome.setParams(alleles)
```

The following code uses a list called "data" for define the ranges.

```
from pyevolve import GAllele
from pyevolve import G1DList
from pyevolve import GSimpleGA
from pyevolve import Crossovers
from pyevolve import Initializators
from pyevolve import Mutators
from pyevolve import Scaling

# data values are the [min, max] for each parameter
data=[ [0,99], [1,10], [1,10], [90,110], [1,10],
[1,10], [1,10], [1,10], [1,10], [1,10],
[1,10], [5,10], [1,10], [1,10], [50,100],
[50,100], [50,100], [50,100], [50,100], [7,77] ]

def Grid_Constructor(a=data):
    alleles = GAllele.GAlleles()
    for i in range(0, 20):
        alleles.add(GAllele.GAlleleRange(a[i][0], a[i][1], real=True))
    return alleles

# set the params, initializator and mutator
genome = G1DList.G1DList(20)
genome.setParams(allele=Grid_Constructor())
genome.initializator.set(Initializators.G1DListInitializatorAllele)
genome.mutator.set(Mutators.G1DListMutatorAllele)
ga = GSimpleGA.GSimpleGA(genome)
print(Grid_Constructor())
#ga.evolve(freq_stats=10)
```

The output for this code is:

```
- GAlleles
    Homogeneous:     False
    List size:   20
    Alleles:

Allele for 0 position:
- GAlleleRange
    Real:        True
    Ranges Count:    1
    Range List:
             Range from [0] to [99]

Allele for 1 position:
- GAlleleRange
    Real:        True
    Ranges Count:    1
    Range List:
             Range from [1] to [10]

Allele for 2 position:
- GAlleleRange
    Real:        True
    Ranges Count:    1
    Range List:
             Range from [1] to [10]

.
.
.

Allele for 19 position:
- GAlleleRange
    Real:        True
    Ranges Count:    1
    Range List:
             Range from [7] to [77]




------------------
(program exited with code: 0)
Press return to continue
```